# Batch Execution Mode won't work with the Table API?

Tags: apache-flink

According to this [article](https://flink.apache.org/2021/03/11/batch-execution-mode.html) the timeline should look like below:

[image: Timeline of batch mode]

However mine timeline looks like this - still parallel [image]:

Unable to set the execution mode from command line so I am using the programmatical approach. Is batch mode supported with the Table API?

```
    final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env);
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
    env.getConfig().setAutoWatermarkInterval(10);
    env.setRuntimeMode(RuntimeExecutionMode.valueOf(RUNTIME_EXECUTION_MODE));
```

Answer (score 0):

As is documented in the [Flink Table API documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/tableapi/) and the [Streaming Concepts page](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/concepts/overview/), the Table API does support Batch mode. When using the SQL Client, you can use `SET 'execution.runtime-mode' = 'batch';`. When using the command line, you can use `-Dexecution.runtime-mode=BATCH`. In code, you would use:

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
env.setRuntimeMode(RuntimeExecutionMode.BATCH);
```

Comment: Hi Martijn, thanks for the quick response. I did the code approach "env.setRuntimeMode(RuntimeExecutionMode.BATCH)" but the timeline shows differently. The tasks are still in parallel.

Comment: I just realized that my flink is 1.13.2. Is this the reason? Thanks

Comment: It could be that it's a visual problem in Flink 1.13, I'm not sure. Batch mode in the Table API is supported in 1.13.